# How to create a column in database that consist of CHARACTER + YEAR + ID (autoincrement) in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

currently I'm developing a new system for my school project. Is there any query or code to create a column that consists of CHARACTER + YEAR + ID (autoincrement) in phpMyAdmin. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't mess with autoincrement. Generate that output on-the-fly when selecting data. You could use 3 different columns and put them together in your SELECT

Comment: Use a computed / generated column